# Enabling Root User SSH access on Plesk

Tags: ssh

How do I enable root user SSH access on Plesk?

Comment: See my answer in http://serverfault.com/questions/189574/allow-root-login-from-one-ip-address-only/189581#189581 (Not sure it works with your specific device though)

Comment: That's how to achieve the result requested - but opensshd provides that config option (and most admins will make use of it) for a very good reason! If you value the security of your system, leave it as-is and use 'su' or 'sudo'

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

What's the OS it's installed on? Plesk won't disable the root user on install, but it's possible that PermitRootLogin is set to no in /etc/ssh/sshd_config as is default in Ubuntu. If that's the case, you need to set it to yes and restart ssh.